# Where does the Bible say that nature will speak the word if men don't?

Tags: new-testament, scriptures

I am trying to remember a verse I've heard, and almost positive I've read, before.

I do not remember the exact phrasing.

It was similar to: 'If no one is there to witness, even the rocks of the field and [trees? mountains? nature?] will witness/speak the word`. I believe this is in the New Testament, possibly Jesus speaking.

What is the passage that relates to what would happen if no one was around to witness?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because verse identification questions are now off-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of [Luke 19:40](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+19:40):

> ‘I tell you [Pharisees],’ he [Jesus] replied, ‘if they [His disciples] keep quiet, the stones will cry out.’

Other passages that refer to the witness of creation include [Psalm 19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+19) and [Romans 1:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+1%3A20).

Comment: Hmmm maybe so, I really thought there is a verse specifically about the absence of witnesses or people to speak the word. Perhaps I am getting mixed up.

Comment: @GaretClaborn: this verse does specify the disciples not speaking. Or did you mean, not specifically preaching *the Gospel* (the word)?

Comment: Yes, at least in my memory, the verse was pertaining to spreading the Gospel and how nothing could prevent it from going forward. Still, it could be that my mind is remembering this verse mixed with another since it seems very close. I'll have to look around a little.

Comment: There's a verse in Acts (I think - I'll have to look it up) that says something about the Gospel being unstoppable - but I don't think it says anything about nature preaching the Gospel.

Answer (score 1):

Romans suggests that knowledge of God can be seen by the created world:

> For since the creation of the world God’s invisible qualities—his
>   eternal power and divine nature—have been clearly seen, being
>   understood from what has been made, so that people are without excuse.
>   (Romans 1:20)

It doesn't say that nature will speak of Jesus, but it will speak of God's character

Comment: Oops, I might have "stolen" your quote without (consciously) realising - sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are thinking of:
Matthew 3:9
"And do not think you can say to yourselves, 'We have Abraham as our father.' I tell you that out of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham."

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.